# View complete API response in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, api, rest

I'm teaching myself Angular as a hobby, so please forgive me if this is a dumb question.

I'm trying to call an external API and view the entire response so I can figure out how to parse it. I have a service with a class like this:

```
export class DataService {

private REST_API_SERVER = 'https://my-api.url';

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  
public sendGetRequest(): Observable<any> {
   return this.httpClient.get(this.REST_API_SERVER);
  }
}
```

Then I have a component that executes a function like this on init:

```
  sendGetRequest(): void {
   var result = this.DataService.sendGetRequest();
  }
```

I've tried using things like:

```
console.log('result: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
```

What gets written to console is:

```
result: {"source":{"source":{"source":{}}}}
```

How can I view the whole response?

Comment: You need to subscribe to the result of the http call. Double check the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your component when you execute the function `sendGetRequest(){}`

try to use it like this

```
sendGetRequest(): void {
  this.DataService.sendGetRequest().subscribe(resp=>{
     console.log(resp)
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!